# Contar registros en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy trabajando con MySQL y necesito realizar una consulta sobre la siguiente tabla llamada `tbl-reserva` que tiene la siguiente estructura:

- `id`
- `fecha_inicio`
- `fecha_fin`
- `descripcion`

La idea es realizar una consulta que cuente, cuántos registros les falta 7 días por vencerse, es decir llegar a su `fecha_fin`, que tiene registrada, comparándola con la fecha del sistema.

Answer (score 4):

Esto te podría ayudar:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tbl-reserva 
WHERE fecha_fin >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Con la función `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY` estás haciendo una resta de la fecha actual contra 7 días antes, y solo se obtendrán los registros donde la `fecha_fin` sea mayor o igual a la fecha que se obtuvo.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo aplica la solución:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tblreserva`;

CREATE TABLE tblreserva (
    id int,
    fecha_inicio datetime,
    fecha_fin datetime,
    descripcion varchar(64)
);

INSERT INTO tblreserva (id, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, descripcion) VALUES (1, '20170101', '20170601', 'Descripción');
INSERT INTO tblreserva (id, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, descripcion) VALUES (2, '20170101', '20170602', 'Descripción');
INSERT INTO tblreserva (id, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, descripcion) VALUES (3, '20170101', '20170603', 'Descripción');
INSERT INTO tblreserva (id, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, descripcion) VALUES (4, '20170101', '20170501', 'Descripción'); #Este registro no cumple con las validaciones

SELECT count(*)
FROM tblreserva
WHERE fecha_fin >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

El resultado es:

```
+---+----------+
|   | count(*) |
+---+----------+
| 1 | 3        |
+---+----------+
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración de la solución](http://rextester.com/JQIYT13014)</kbd>

Comment: la acabo de probar, para la prueba tengo 3 registros que cumplen con los 7 días, me debería contar solo esos, pero me cuanto todos los que tengo en la tabla

Comment: @Criss justo acabo de replicar el ejercicio, revisa la respuesta actualizada, seguramente se te está escapando algún dato en las condiciones de la consulta